# listing folders of parent directory with opendir does not work

Tags: php, parent, opendir

The following script works fine for the current directory:

```
<?php    
$ignore = array ('.', '..', '.DS_Store', 'index.php');
    $num_ordnernamen = array ();
    if ($handle = opendir('./')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if (!in_array($entry, $ignore) && is_dir($entry)) {
        array_push($num_ordnernamen, $entry);
        }
    }
    }
    print_r ($num_ordnernamen); 
?>
```

, it returns the array as it should:

```
Array ( [0] => firstfolder [1] => secondfolder )
```

It does, however, not work for

```
if ($handle = opendir('../')) //or
if ($handle = opendir('..')) //or
if ($handle = opendir('../..'))
```

… or anything else I try to get one level up. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

- Have you permissions to read parent directory?
- Have you error reporting active?
- There are directories in your parent directory? (your code print only directories)